# Jackson deserialize date string with + and t character

Tags: java, json

i have problem with deserialize Json string date: 2020-09-30T07:00:00+02:00
I am getting error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2020-09-30T07:00:00+02:00": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2020-09-30T07:00:00+02:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19
```

Its look like + is and unexcepted character.
Pojo:

```
@JsonProperty("Date")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    public LocalDate date;
```

Any ideas how i can map this string to localdate?

Comment: You are using the wrong class for this. A [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is "A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03". Since your data contains date, time and timezone information, you should look at [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) with its respective `Deserializer`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
@JsonProperty("Date")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
public LocalDate date;
```

Check DateFormat here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Besides you should use another type like ZonedDateTime or java.util.Date instead of LocalDate to get hour, minute and second.